# If I Connect Three 12vDC Power Supplies In Series Can I Make 36vDC Output?

Tags: power-supply, transformer

If I Connect Three 12vDC Power Supplies In Series Can I Make 36vDC Output ?
And If Yes, Please Give Me A Schematic or Wiring Guide For That

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119833/discussion-on-question-by-meow-if-i-connect-three-12vdc-power-supplies-in-series).

Comment: Note: Safety - 36V is "often enough" touch safe. People have died from 36V contact, sadly. I've had numerous 48V minor / nuisance shocks (telephone exchange wiring frame during engineering training lonnnnnng ago, high humidity) BUT I'd always treat 36V as 'potentially' lethal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose line-input AC-to-DC supplies that have isolated outputs. This kind of supply has an internal transformer between the primary and secondary that allows the output to float with respect to the line input, or to chassis ground. This will be the case for closed-frame switchers intended for IT and industrial use.

Example: https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/MEAN-WELL/PSPA-1000-12/

With this kind of supply you can connect their outputs in series, head to tail, and connect their AC inputs in common, as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkTWU4m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Two considerations:

- If the supply has a chassis GND strap to the 'GND' output, remove it so the secondary side can float.
- Size the wiring as needed for both the main in and out, and for the jumpers. You specified 80A for a 3KW supply, so #3ga or larger, or its equivalent in smaller wires.

Finally... **NOTE: This does not work if the outputs are not isolated.** Example: multiple non-isolated DC-DC converters cannot be connected this way.

Comment: It is good idea to use triple pole DC MCB/MCCB for protection ?, Pole 1 : Power Supply 1 (+), Pole 2 : Power Supply 1 (-) <---> Power Supply 2 (+), Pole 3 : Power Supply 2 (-) <---> Power Supply 3 (+) ?, so if there is over current all load is cut's together

Comment: And what's AWG cable size do you advice ?, that power supply is 80a, and also are you sure it's good idea to series that three 12v 80a power supply in series ?, because this circuit is nearly 3kw

Comment: The current will be limited by OC trip of any one supply, since they're wired in series. So long as that OC trip is what you need, then no external circuit is needed. If you need an explicit protection circuit for +36V, it only needs to be on the one +36V line. As for the wire size, use #3ga or larger wire, or use multiple smaller wires to get the current capacity needed. More here: https://www.cerrowire.com/products/resources/tables-calculators/ampacity-charts/

Comment: What's if there is voltage imbalance between those supply ?, let's say one is 12v and another is 12.8v ?, note : those supply is adjustable from 10-14v from potentiometer, but not really exactly at constant voltages

Comment: Then the sum voltage will be off - it'll be 36.8V instead of your target 36V. In the big picture, that's only a 2.2% error. How accurate does it need to be? If it's anything less than 10%, you probably need a different solution than cobbling together three +12V supplies.

Comment: Ok... Is there any protection from human touching 36v DC wire ?, is ground earthed input and output is enough ?

Comment: It's also good idea to supply those power supply from one phase only, or one power supply for each phase (RST) ?

Comment: 36V is 'touch-safe', meaning that in ordinary use it does not present a hazard. That said, high current, make sure the wires can stay cool. The input current for 3kW is about 13A (230V.) This is beyond a standard single 6A outlet (or whatever passes for one in Russia.) You need a higher current single-phase plug (like for a dryer or oven). 3-phase can work too, wire the inputs as a 'wye' with a common neutral.

Comment: Are you certain that **all** "line-input AC-to-DC supplies" are in fact isolated and can safely be connected in series? Not just most, but **all**?

Comment: Here are some non-isolated, ac mains in, 12V dc out, supplies where the negative output terminal is wired directly to the ac neutral. https://www.mornsun-power.com/html/news-detail/product-news/290.html

Comment: @ElliotAlderson: Yes. If they're line input, off-the-shelf type (and not some special design meant to be part of an enclosure), to meet safety they will be isolated.

Comment: If I can buy it from Mouser is it "off-the-shelf"? Which safety standards exactly require isolation? I think you have made a generalization that risks the safety of the readers here. How hard is it to say "Make sure the outputs are isolated"?

Comment: Don't be a pest. This is already a noisy question.

Comment: @hacktastical 36V is "often enough" touch safe. People have died from 36V contact, sadly. I've had numerous 48V minor / nuisance shocks (telephone exchange wiring frame during engineering training lonnnnnng ago, high humidity) BUT I'd always treat 36V as 'potentially' lethal.

Comment: 60VDC is the SELV limit. From a regulatory standpoint (e.g., EN90650-1, now superceded by ISO 62368-1) anything below that is considered 'touch safe'.

Comment: Soooo, schematic is exactly like i wrote +-+-+-. Nice. Downvote me more please.

Comment: @Hedgehog I didn't downvote you. But the Q needed more of a complete explanation than you offered. Something to think about going forward.

Answer (score -3):

Connect is as you would connect 3 batteries. +-+-+-
Voltage between first + and last - is 36V

Edit:
Lol

I've literaly done this and it works.

Comment: This works with ideal voltage sources, but no real world supplies are ideal voltage sources so it is not a given that it will work. Real world supplies need isolation between their power input and output or else they will form a short when put in series. The outputs also need to be constructed such that they can actually pass current from external sources through their output terminals.

Comment: Sorry... you can't do that, is practically dangerous for humans, and can damage power supply permanently

Comment: Yes... @DKNguyen is true